# Print charactes as their escaped versions rather than codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

e.g how do I print `\b` as '\b' rather than '\x08'?

My current attempt is: `value = repr(value)[1:-1]`, but that just prints out the code.

It seemed to work fine for `\t` and `\n`, but doesn't work for backspace

Comment: Do raw strings solve your problem: `r"\b"`?

Comment: A very similar question was asked not so long ago. Sadly, I cannot find it. If I am not mistaken, there is no consistent way to display escaped characters literally. `repr` works for some characters but not for all.

Comment: `str()` and `repr()` have default handling.  If you don't like the default. Write your own function and replace it yourself.  Something like `'a\bc'.replace('\b',r'\b')`

Answer (score 1):

`repr` doesn't know about all the backslash escapes; besides your `\b` (BS="backspace") example, there are also `\a` ("alert", for the BEL character that should make your terminal beep), `\f` (FF="form feed", which originally moved to a new piece of paper in the printer and clears some terminal screens), and `\v` (for VT="vertical tab"), for which `repr` similarly returns hex codes (`'\x07'`, `'\x0c'`, and `'\x0b'`, respectively). Your best bet is probably to roll your own function that does the replacements you want, e.g.:

```
def compact_repr(s):
  r = repr(s)
  for x, b in { r'\x07': r'\a', r'\x08': r'\b', 
                r'\x0b': r'\v', r'\x0c': r'\f' }.items():
    r = r.replace(x, b)
  return r
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your own function if you don't like the `repr()` default.  Here's a brute force way to handle escape codes that `repr()` doesn't:

```py
def better_repr(s):
    return repr(s).replace(r'\x07',r'\a').replace(r'\x08',r'\b').replace(r'\x0b',r'\v').replace(r'\x0c',r'\f')

print(repr('\a\b\n\r\t\v\f'))
print(better_repr('\a\b\n\r\t\v\f'))
```

Output:

```
'\x07\x08\n\r\t\x0b\x0c'
'\a\b\n\r\t\v\f'
```